# I am unable to integrate horizontal Scroll View in my view controller in Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, scrollview

I am trying to integrate horizontal scrollview in my view controller (Swift) Xcode project.! As there is no error, but the scroll view does not work, as there is no scroll. 
The size of horizontal scroll view is (Width = 414) and (height = 100).

The Scroll view contains UIImages and Buttons.

I have tried several things, But nothing is working out.! I am using - Swift 3 and Xcode 8.1

[image: I Want the UIImages to scroll]

Comment: scrollview works while its content size larger than its self size .

Comment: Yes the content size is bigger than the scroll view, As scroll view contains 20 UIImages and That is bigger than the scroll views width(414)

Comment: please add that code in questions so we can understand .

Comment: Please, add more information to clarify the question. Do you add images in code? Then post the code here.

Comment: I have not integrated any code with scroll view.

Comment: Also I have added a screenshot of the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this in the interface builder without any code you need to set content size for you scroll view.

1. Select you scroll view in IB.
2. Open Identity Inspector in the right panel and find **User Defined Runtime Attributes** there.

[image]

3. Add attribute (with the plus sign). Rename `keyPath` into `contentSize`, change **Type** from `Boolean` to `Size` and set the **Value** to the one you need (width is the sum of your images' widths).

Comment: Thanks for the help, But i have a problem.! I have 17 UIImages that are 80x80 so, In contentSize (Width 1360) - The problem  I am having is that the Scroll view does not show all the images, instead only shows two Rows in the simulator.

Comment: Also, Now I want to use it Vertically.! I don't think that it is scrolling, it like it is Bouncing.

Comment: @AshishVerma I don't think you can do everything in the interface builder then. Try to find a basic scroll view tutorial, for now your question is too broad.